# Set a default URL parameter if none is specified or is blank

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, parameter-passing, url-parameters

I have this code:

```
    function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1] || ''
    );
}
```

In my HTML, I call out a user's device brand and model using:

```
<script>document.write(getURLParameter("brand") + (" ") + getURLParameter("name"))</script>
```

The only problem is that this is only working for certain mobile devices. When it doesn't work, it's simply left blank. Is there a way to add a default value if it's empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare the values with

```
if(name === " " || name == null) {
    //code
}
```

or

```
if(name !== " " || name != null) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1] || ''
    );
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure how that's implemented (I'm a newbie)  
``function getURLParameter(name) {
 if(name === " " || name == null) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1] || ''
    );
}
}``  

Everything is still blank when there's no value.

Comment: In Js when a variable has no value it by default null, so when you get a value as parameter it can be null. Just check that inside the function before decoding the variable's value.

Comment: I still can't figure out how to do this :(  To clarify, I'd like to set a default value for the return value, not the actual parameter name. For example &brand=Samsung.  If "Samsung" is not present in the URL, I want it to be replaced with "Mobile Device"

Comment: Before sending the variable put the first condition and if its true change the value to "Mobile Device",

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but as I said I'm still just a beginner. Is there somewhere I can read up on how to do this specific task? I don't even know where to start.